# How to Query a Read-Only Field with ORMLite

Tags: ormlite, readonly

I am trying ORMLite as an ORM for a project I am developing. I am mapping a java class to a table that has some auditing fields (ie. updatedby, updatedtime, etc.). The auditing fields are maintained by the database using triggers to ensure that no matter what front-end the user is using these fields will always be correctly updated when a record is updated.

I need to include these fields in my client application to inform the user when the record was last updated, but the user can't change them. Is there a way to annotate the class so that ORMLite won't try to perform updates on these fields or include them in insert statements. The database will deny an update if these fields are included in an update statement (which is why I can't just write back the original value that was queried from the database).

I tried using the `@DatabaseField(persisted = false)` annotation on the Java fields, but then they don't get queried at all so the Java object is never populated with these fields.

Basically, I need these fields to be included in `SELECT` statements, but not included in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements (equivalent to a `@DatabaseField(immutable = true)` annotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting pattern.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) didn't support the feature at the time but now it does as of version 4.46.

There is now a `@DatabaseField(readOnly=true)` annotation field.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your quick response. I just switched to ORMLite two days ago after struggling with Hibernate and am very enthusiastic about my ORMLite experience so far. Your quick, helpful and encouraging response to my question only reinforces my enthusiasm about using ORMLite. Also, the ORMLite userguide is (IMHO) one of the most well written, useful, and even a bit enjoyable to work through, manuals I have seen. It got me up and running extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks @Casey.  I've spent a lot of time on the docs.  Glad it wasn't in vain.  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't often have cycles to be so responsive.  So feel free to ping me using the mailing list if you don't get a resolution.

Comment: I noticed that it only works when you set both @DatabaseField(persisted = false, readOnly = true). You might consider updating it for the next formal release so that it will also work if you only set @DatabaseField(readOnly = true).

Comment: I think that it only works correctly on create statements, but not update statements. I think that you may need to update "if" clause in the MappedUpdated.isFieldUpdatable method to also include "fieldType.isReadOnly()".

Comment: Whoops.  You are right @Casey.  Didn't try update.  I've pushed that change to the repo.   https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/40dca0173c03ace5c929f7ce21d27829d650b6eb